# method to an instance sending a similar object as a parameter?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I need to send a method to an instance, in this method, the receiver instance has to compare `self` against another instance of the same class, passed later as a parameter.

To be more clear: class `Handler` has a method called `define_method (param)` that defines a new method to the instance `inst` (`inst` will be the parameter of `define_method`) that has the class `X`. So, from now `inst` has the ability to compare itself against another `X` instance just calling the method (the way the instances are compared does not matter right now).

```
inst.compare(anotherInst)
```

How can I do to implement the `define_changes(inst)` knowing that the instances could be any object that `Handler` does not know?

Comment: maybe `define_singleton_method`? Although it's a little hard to understand what you mean by all this, can you show an attempt to fill in the functions and what the desired vs actual output is?

Comment: @maxpleaner I edited the question, simplifying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really understand what you want to do, but you can add method to an instantiated object in this way:

```
irb(main):135:0> s = 'foobar'
=> "foobar"
irb(main):136:0> s.define_singleton_method(:foobar?) { self == 'foobar' }
=> :foobar?
irb(main):137:0> s.foobar?
=> true
```

But your functionality's description sounds a little bit tricky. Maybe you need to change your approach